# express server returns errors on start

Tags: express, server, webpack

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why my server returns errors when I start it. I'm not using webpack-dev-server because it doesn't compile JS files so I decided to make my own server. When I opened my browser, it displayed an error message that says:[image]

`server.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path'),
    express = require('express'),
    devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware'),
    hotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware'),
    config = require('./webpack.config'),
    app = express(),
    host = '127.0.0.1',
    port = 8000;

var middleware = devMiddleware(webpack({
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'app/src/main.js'),
  output: {
    path: '/',
  }
}), {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  index: path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.html'),
  stats: {
    colors: true
  }
});

app.use(middleware);

app.use(hotMiddleware(webpack(config)));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.write(middleware.fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.html')));
  res.end();
});

app.listen(port, host, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  console.log('Listening on ' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

project files and directories:
[image]

I don't understand why this is happening. Maybe I'm missing a lot of important plugins or dependencies to make it successful like react-hot-loader? Or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you shouldn't be using `middleware.fileSystem.readFileSync()` to handle requests for `index.html` (which isn't part of your bundle).

Just use `fs.readFileSync()` or, preferably, `res.sendFile()`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: so I should require `fs` in my `server.js`?

Comment: @jst.sixteen if you want to use `fs.readFileSync()`, then yes.